# How to add a new user to Mailchimp campaign using cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mailchimp

I am trying to add the new user to the Mailchimp campaign. I get two errors the first one says:

`Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value`

Second error's log is  :

```
Error: The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.
  type: 'http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/',
  title: 'Invalid Resource',
  status: 400,
  detail: 'The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the \'errors\' array.',
  instance: '549e8553-5ef1-4600-9271-07255f4673fe',
  errors: 
   [ { field: 'status',
       message: 'The value you selected is not a valid choice.' } ] }
```

This is my function

```
   exports.userCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const email = user.email;
    // const displayName = user.name;

    // make Mailchimp API request to add a user
    Mailchimp
      .post('/lists/id/members', {
        email_address: email,
        status: 'Signed Up',
        // optional: requires additional setup
        merge_fields: {
          "EMAIL" : email
        }
      })
      .then(function(results) {
        console.log('Successfully added new Firebase user', email, 'to Mailchimp list',results);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(email);
        console.log('Mailchimp: Error while attempting to add registered subscriber —', err);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two errors in your Cloud Function, as you have detected:

The first one is that you MUST return a Promise (or a value) in your background triggered Cloud Function, to indicate to the platform that it has completed. Please watch the three videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) for more details on this key point.

The second problem is that your value for the field `status` "is not a valid choice". Have a look at the Mailchimp [doc](https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/#Contact_status), if I am not mistaking, the correct values are:

`subscribed`, `pending`, `unsubscribed` or `cleaned`.

---

So, the following changes should do the trick:

```
   exports.userCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const email = user.email;
    // const displayName = user.name;

    // make Mailchimp API request to add user
    return mailchimp
      .post('/lists/id/members', {
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed',   // For example, it's up to you to find the correct status
        // optional: requires additional setup
        merge_fields: {
          "EMAIL" : email
        }
      })
      .then(function(results) {
        console.log('Successfully added new Firebase user', email, 'to Mailchimp list',results);
        return null;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(email);
        console.log('Mailchimp: Error while attempting to add registered subscriber —', err);
        return null;
      });
  });
```